# Alternative to this query

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to get all the articles in my database which are the most viewed the past day, week or month.

This is why I use these queries (I use the results of the first query for creating the last )

```
SELECT guid
FROM tracking
WHERE date > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
GROUP BY guid
ORDER BY count(guid) DESC limit 1,10 

SELECT *
FROM `items`
WHERE `id` IN('66', '37', '42', '50', '55', '38',   '41', '65', '71', '44') AND `type` = 'ddl'
ORDER BY FIELD(id, 66, 37, 42, 50, 55, 38, 41, 65, 71, 44)
```

Is there another way to obtain the same results very fast? Currently, the response time is 0.4530ms for only 45 records on tracking table & 36 records on items table.

**EXPLAIN**

[image]

Comment: You should replace the list of the `IN` condition with the first query. Do you have an indices on `guid` and `date` for example?

Comment: yes i have created an index for guid

Comment: I suspect, the problem is not with the statements, but with the environment. With only 45 and 36 records, the queries should run fast, no matter what.

Comment: You should use `EXPLAIN` as mentioned by @BerndBuffen

Comment: Explain added in my question :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to keep the order based on counts in the second query, you can use JOIN to combine the two like this:

```
SELECT 
    a.*
FROM
    `items` a
        INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        guid, COUNT(guid) cnt
    FROM
        tracking
    WHERE
        date > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
    GROUP BY guid
    ORDER BY COUNT(guid) DESC
    LIMIT 1 , 10) b ON a.`id` = b.guid
WHERE
    a.`type` = 'ddl'
ORDER BY b.cnt DESC;
```

Comment: Unfortunately i obtain the same result time (0.4710 ms) :(

Comment: can you show us the output from EXPLAIN of this query to see if all indexes are ok

Comment: Explain added in my question :)